# Paypal Android SDK

Tags: paypal

No implementation found for boolean io.card.payment.CardScanner.nUseX86()
Not able to get Scanner feature in Android paypal when integrate in Project. Demo works fine.

```
 private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
                // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
        .merchantName("Example Merchant")
        .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
        .acceptCreditCards(true)
        .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you're missing the native libraries for card.io. Make sure the libs directory exists in your project and [looks like this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/tree/master/libs).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. but i already put all required library which you have mention in link.